# Rstudio, fill boroughs with coordinates

Tags: r

I'm working on a New York Collisions dataset (https://www.kaggle.com/nypd/vehicle-collisions) and I'm having problems with the boroughs, some of them are perfect with its borough etc.. but others are blank with its coordinates. How could I fill the unknown (desconocido) ones? 
I have tried this:

```
BOROUGH2 <- ifelse(accidentes2$LATITUDE>=40.7831 & accidentes2$LONGITUDE<=-73.9712,"MANHATTAN", 0)

BOROUGH2 <- ifelse(accidentes2$LATITUDE>=40.7282 & accidentes2$LONGITUDE<=-73.7949,"QUEENS", 0)

BOROUGH2 <- ifelse(accidentes2$LATITUDE>=40.6782 & accidentes2$LONGITUDE<=-73.9442,"BROOKLYN", 0)

BOROUGH2 <- ifelse(accidentes2$LATITUDE>=40.8448 & accidentes2$LONGITUDE<=-73.8648,"BRONX", 0)

BOROUGH2 <- ifelse(accidentes2$LATITUDE>=40.49913 & accidentes2$LONGITUDE<=-74.24348,"STATEN ISLAND",0)

accidentes2 <- data.frame(accidentes2,BOROUGH2)
```

but it doesn´t work.

The idea obviously is with those coordinates to change the borough to the right one instead of `desconocido` (unknown).
Thanks a lot

Comment: You'll need to supply an example of your data you're having issues with.

Comment: You are right, sorry.

I have tried uploading a picture but I can´t

This is the dataset:

https://www.kaggle.com/nypd/vehicle-collisions

As you can see, there are many empty or NA spaces in the borough column but you can know the exact borugh from the coordinates.